# Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected is always false

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Could someone explain why property `IsRequestBeingRedirected` is always false in my code and how to redirect correctly to get true value?

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected)
    {
        //some another logic
    }
    //some code       
    filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IsRequestBeingRedirected` property is set to true *during* the call to `Response.Redirect`. Here is the source code via .NET Reflector:

```
public void Redirect(string url)
{
    this.Redirect(url, true, false);
}

public void Redirect(string url, bool endResponse)
{
    this.Redirect(url, endResponse, false);
}

internal void Redirect(string url, bool endResponse, bool permanent)
{
    if (url == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("url");
    }
    if (url.IndexOf('\n') >= 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(System.Web.SR.GetString("Cannot_redirect_to_newline"));
    }
    if (this._headersWritten)
    {
        throw new HttpException(System.Web.SR.GetString("Cannot_redirect_after_headers_sent"));
    }
    Page page = this._context.Handler as Page;
    if ((page != null) && page.IsCallback)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(System.Web.SR.GetString("Redirect_not_allowed_in_callback"));
    }
    url = this.ApplyRedirectQueryStringIfRequired(url);
    url = this.ApplyAppPathModifier(url);
    url = this.ConvertToFullyQualifiedRedirectUrlIfRequired(url);
    url = this.UrlEncodeRedirect(url);
    this.Clear();
    if (((page != null) && page.IsPostBack) && (page.SmartNavigation && (this.Request["__smartNavPostBack"] == "true")))
    {
        this.Write("<BODY><ASP_SMARTNAV_RDIR url=\"");
        this.Write(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(url));
        this.Write("\"></ASP_SMARTNAV_RDIR>");
        this.Write("</BODY>");
    }
    else
    {
        this.StatusCode = permanent ? 0x12d : 0x12e;
        this.RedirectLocation = url;
        if (UriUtil.IsSafeScheme(url))
        {
            url = HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(url);
        }
        else
        {
            url = HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url));
        }
        this.Write("<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>\r\n");
        this.Write("<h2>Object moved to <a href=\"" + url + "\">here</a>.</h2>\r\n");
        this.Write("</body></html>\r\n");
    }

    // IsRequestBeingRedirected is set here
    this._isRequestBeingRedirected = true;
    EventHandler redirecting = Redirecting;
    if (redirecting != null)
    {
        redirecting(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    if (endResponse)
    {
        this.End();
    }
}
```

So you have to check the value after you call `Response.Redirect` for it to be true.

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

    //some code       
    filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath);

    if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected)
    {
        //some another logic
    }
}
```

Of course, your logic isn't very clear. You already know that you are redirecting because you are calling `Response.Redirect`, so checking this property seems redundant in this case.

Comment: I'm just trying to write logic for detecting if cookies were disabled in browser in runtime. I have no idea how to realize this by another way..

Comment: If you search on Google, there are many solutions for cookie checking already. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716710/how-to-check-cookie-enabled-for-the-browser-or-not#4149481) looks promising.